# Does Thread.Sleep(x) interfere with Timer/Stopwatch?

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering if there are any unseen consequences of using Thread.Sleep(x) in my program while running Timers or a StopWatch...

I have a stopwatch that is running to count the time between user button presses and a Timer that ticks at 1s intervals to update a clock.

Will using Thread.Sleep(x) while either of these are running cause problems with accurate timing? (Most importantly the stopwatch)

Comment: Why do you need to ask us that when you can easily test it for yourself?

Comment: Thank you Mitch, I don't think I'll have any problems then. Their relation is understood better when you say it so simply.

Comment: If Sleep will effect the timer depends on if the timer is running its ticks on the UI thread and the sleep is also on the UI thread. Are both of those two things true?

Comment: @Scott, I just took a stab at explaining that in answer form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing can directly interfere with a `Stopwatch`; the object is passive, only updating when started or stopped, and reporting and reacting based on the return values of the low-level [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) API.  Power-management events such as suspend, hibernation, or dynamic CPU clock speed variation are the few things that can cause problems with this.

As for the `Timer` classes... which one, and does it need to manipulate UI objects when it fires?  If so, don't just `Sleep` on the UI thread, no matter which timer you choose.

[`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is bound to the thread it was created on, and if that thread blocks without pumping messages (which `Sleep` will do) its `Tick` event will be delayed until that thread can pump events again.

[`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) will queue its tick to the thread pool, so barring massive interference it is unlikely to be disrupted.  However, due to use of the thread pool, the tick handler cannot directly manipulate UI objects; it will need to marshal the call to the UI thread with [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx), and `Invoke` will block if the UI thread is sleeping or otherwise not pumping messages.

[`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably the most complicated of the lot; it can be configured with a [synchronization provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) to marshal the calls to the correct synchronization context, but it too can do nothing to update the UI if the UI thread is sleeping or otherwise not pumping messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of broad to answer depending on the how you are actually going to use them...with no code this is harder to explain how it's going to work in your code...

Sleep causes a program to suspend operation. This Subroutine receives one parameter, which indicates the number of milliseconds to pause the program. No CPU time is used by Sleep. The program simply ceases to operate.

With this in mind, it will stop the program in general (pause), but a stopwatch will continue to tick as it's on a different thread... See example...

```
' Create a Stopwatch and sleep for 5 seconds.
Dim stopwatch As Stopwatch = stopwatch.StartNew
Thread.Sleep(5000)
stopwatch.Stop()
```

The stopwatch will run no matter what until you stop it...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and it might be that you are having similar trivial problem. 
stopwatch.Elapsed has two different properties, which you might mix up like I did:

This one will give you seconds as a remainder of a time passed:

```
stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds
```

while this one will give you total number of seconds passed:

```
stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

so if you have something like:

```
while (stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 61)
{
    //do something
}
```

you will have infinite loop, like I had and this answer just sent me on the tour of researching timers :)